# How to search array and display in Text Box?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to figure out how I can search my array and then have the entry I'm looking for displayed in the original textbox.

```
        If idTextBox.Text = String.Empty Or nameTextBox.Text = String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid name and/or ID number.")
    Else
        'retrieve user input & add to array
        studentArray(0, columnId) = idTextBox.Text
        studentArray(1, columnId) = nameTextBox.Text
        studentArray(2, columnId) = majorComboBox.Text
        studentArray(3, columnId) = yearComboBox.Text
        If honorsRadioButton.Checked = True Then
            studentArray(4, columnId) = "1"
        ElseIf notHonorsRadioButton.Checked = True Then
            studentArray(4, columnId) = "0"
        End If
```

This is the search and display code I have, it crashes when I search for an ID not present in the array.

```
Dim findstudentid As Integer
Dim didFindIt As Boolean = False
Integer.TryParse(idTextBox.Text, findstudentid)

If findstudentid <> 0 Then
    Dim foundIt As Integer
    Dim highColumn As Integer = studentArray.GetUpperBound(0)

    'search each column of the first row
    For columnID As Integer = 0 To highColumn
        If findstudentid = CDbl(studentArray(0, columnID)) Then
            foundIt = columnID
            didFindIt = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If didFindIt Then
        'read from array and write to interface
        idTextBox.Text = studentArray(0, foundIt)
        nameTextBox.Text = studentArray(1, foundIt)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Student data is not found. Please re-enter or add the student data!", "Student Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

        idTextBox.Focus()
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a student id.", "Student Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    idTextBox.Focus()
End If
```

Comment: where the search code - none of that seems related to the question

Comment: A custom class would be a better choice than an array. Your student has 5 properties that define it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of an OOP way to do it. With this function you can check the return value for a null/Nothing found before calling it's properties(would error). You can even do DataBinding with the object or it's `List(Of T)`.

```
Public Class Student
 Public Property Id As Integer
 Public Property Name As String
 Public Property Major As String
 Public Property Year As Integer
 Public Property Honors As Boolean
End Class
```

In your form:

```
Public Class FrmMain : Inherits Form
 Private Students As New List(Of Student)

 Private Sub btnNewStudent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewStudent.Click
  Dim _student As New Student
  'fill the properties 
  Students.Add(_student)
 End Sub
 '...
End Class
Private Function FindStudent(Id As Integer) As Student
  'return the student by Id or object with by Nothing
  Return Students.Where(Function(s) s.Id = Id).FirstOrDefault
End Function
```

Comment: +1 nice and simple, I like the inline search function (haven't quite got the hang of writing these just yet so it's always nice to see an example).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
    Dim findstudentid As Integer
    Dim didFindIt As Boolean = False
    Integer.TryParse(idTextBox.Text, findstudentid)

    If findstudentid <> 0 Then
        Dim foundIt As Integer
        Dim highColumn As Integer = studentArray.GetUpperBound(0)

        'search each column of the first row
        For columnID As Integer = 0 To highColumn
            If findstudentid = CDbl(studentArray(0, columnID)) Then
                foundIt = columnID
                didFindIt = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If didFindIt Then
            'read from array and write to interface
            idTextBox.Text = studentArray(0, foundIt)
            nameTextBox.Text = studentArray(1, foundIt)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Student data is not found. Please re-enter or add the student data!", "Student Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

            idTextBox.Focus()
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a student id.", "Student Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        idTextBox.Focus()
    End If
```

Comment: Actually my program now crashes when I try to search for an id not stored in an array.